# How do I set SysTick to 1 ms?

Tags: stm32, arm

I am using STM32F100xx and want to set the SysTick timer to 1 ms. How could I do it?

I am reading this part from the reference manual, but I can't understand fully.

> **SysTick calibration value register**
>
> The SysTick calibration value is set to 9000, which gives a reference
>   time base of 3 ms with the SysTick clock set to 3 MHz (max HCLK/8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Systick is a feature of the Cortex-M core, therefore it's usage is covered in [PM0056 Programming manual STM32F10xxx/20xxx/21xxx/L1xxxx Cortex-M3](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/5b/ca/8d/83/56/7f/40/08/CD00228163.pdf/files/CD00228163.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00228163.pdf).

First, set the preload register, the value should be your clock frequency in kHz minus 1.

```
SysTick->LOAD = 72000 - 1;
```

then set the control register: source is AHB clock, enable interrupt (if you want to), enable clock.

```
SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;
```

Then it's up and running. Leave the calibration value alone.

Comment: This gives me 3ms, I put 8000 instead of 72000 so gives me exact 1ms, thank you.